# Flow does not recognize a refinement of disjoint union of tuples

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-js

Is there a way to refine a union of tuples correctly in flow? I see examples for object types in docs but looks like it has a difference for arrays and I don't see any clue for that case.
I have this simple code:

```
/* @flow */

type A = ['a', string, string];
type B = ['b', number];

function process(param: A | B) {
  if (param[0] === 'a') {
    /*
     ERROR! Cannot get `param[2]` because `B` [1] only has 2 elements, 
     so index 2 is out of bounds. [invalid-tuple-index] 
    */
    console.log(param[2])
  } else {
    console.log(param[1])
  }
}
```

[Flow Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGANoDkAhpQDRgDOGATgJYB2A5g8+9wF0A3JlwEAQqQqUARvTAcArgFsZeFsPRRFHAMYY2cDmBws4uvI0YAKHNRbVlALiJgAPmHEBKMAG9UYGBsUGC29o7kAAwCpCRkNJQ+-oGBoAEpYACiAErZAPLZAIRgAMLUHBxwGGBceNUABnYOyuQATAL1YGq61IqMBPXineQAjDFGMFhgABbUjGCtYHgweMp4HBiMDOkpjHBBHAAmeAAeC0HzcIrVcCEyV0eMAHQUnABu1DBshwC0GIo4FY-TjHE4xHbINAZXRGPYrJ7wLhhZptARedIAXyWMH6fghMI4cLwCLgSKaETG6MCGNQGKAA)

But in typescript it distinguishes types correctly

```
type A = ['a', string, string];
type B = ['b', number];

function process(param: A | B) {
  if (param[0] === 'a') {
    console.log(param[2]) // Works! param: A
  } else {
    console.log(param[1]) // param: B
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not supported. There's an open PR https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/5048

Length based refinement is already implemented though: param[0] === 'a' -> param.length === 3